# Regex redirecting page to unwanted page

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, url-rewriting

I am using htaccess to clean URL, following is rule for profile page

```
RewriteRule ^([0-9a-z]+)$ profile.php?user=$1
```

but I have other pages like followers, following of loggedin user who can see their followers at `/followers` page and the rule for this is

```
RewriteRule ^following$ follow.php?follow=following
RewriteRule ^followers$ follow.php?follow=followers
```

but when I go to `/followers` I am getting redirected to `profile.php`(first rule above), as you can see in first rule anything after domain name `localhost/text_that_comes_here` goes to `profile.php`

what could be the solution so that my `/followers` and other pages will be redirected correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should put the more specific rules before the more generic ones.
In this case, the rules `^following$` and `^followers$` are more specific than `^([0-9a-z]+)$`... 
Which will cause "following" and "followers" to get catched by the first rule `^([0-9a-z]+)$`, and therefore redirecting to `profile.php`

Reordering your .htaccess as the following should do the trick:

```
RewriteRule ^following$ follow.php?follow=following
RewriteRule ^followers$ follow.php?follow=followers
RewriteRule ^([0-9a-z]+)$ profile.php?user=$1
```

**Edit:** to answer your comment, here's a method you could use to do it programmatically: 
*However, it’s is kind of a hack and I wouldn’t use this as a permanent fix.

Since it will redirect to  `profile.php?user=following` (or `profile.php?user=followers`), what you could do is add a condition in the beginning of the `profile.php` page and check if the parameter `$_GET["user"]="following"` (or "followers").
Something like:

```
if ($_GET["user"]="following" || $_GET["user"]="followers") {
    $_GET["follow"]=$_GET["user"]; //set the parameter required in “follow.php”
    include("follow.php");
    exit;
}
```

That implies that you won’t be able to have any user named `following` or  `follower`, which shouldn’t happen anyway… but still.

Comment: I already tried this, and yes this works, but that will be an adjustment, couldn't there be any programmatic way of solving this problem?

Comment: I edited my answer to add a programmatic way to do it. However, it is less cleaner way to do it.